# Рекурсия и while True в python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Сижу тренирую рекурсию, не получается, через while True (получается), туже задачу через рекурсию ну никак

```
while True:
    a = int(input("vvedete pervoe cheslo"))
    b = int(input("vvedete pervoe cheslo"))

    if a > 5 and b > 5:
        print(a / b)

    else:
        print("Finish")
        break
```

а вот мой пример на рекурсию

```
def xcv(a, b):
    if a > 5 and b > 5:
        print(a / b)
        xcv(a, b)

    else:
        print("Finish")


xcv(int(input("vvedete pervoe cheslo")), int(input("vvedete vtoroe cheslo")))
```

в рекурсии он бесконечно делает, а не каждый раз по нвоой спрашивает

Comment: попробуйте заменить `xcv(a, b)`  на  `xcv(int(input("vvedete pervoe cheslo")), int(input("vvedete vtoroe cheslo")))`

Comment: Когда вы вызываете `print(a / b)` , у вас значения a и b остаются теми же.

Comment: @S.Nick спасибо, заработало)))

Answer (score 1):

Ваш код с рекурсией не работает по причине, что переменные `a` и `b` остаются те же *(Вы вызывали `xcv(a, b)` внутри этой же функции, а `a` и `b` не изменяли)*.

Вот измененный код, в котором функция не принимает какие-либо аргументы, а ввод значений `a` и `b` выполняется внутри функции *(чтобы код выглядел аккуратнее и не имел повторяющихся частей):*

```
def xcv():
    a = int(input("vvedite pervoe chislo"))
    b = int(input("vvedite pervoe chislo"))

    if a > 5 and b > 5:
        print(a / b)
        xcv()

    else:
        print("Finish")
```

Если Вы все-таки хотите, чтобы функция принимала аргументы, предлагаю второй вариант:

```
def xcv(a, b):
    if a > 5 and b > 5:
        print(a / b)
        xcv(int(input("vvedite pervoe chislo")), int(input("vvedite vtoroe chislo")))

    else:
        print("Finish")

xcv(int(input("vvedete pervoe cheslo")), int(input("vvedete vtoroe cheslo")))
```

Или можете использовать стандартные значения аргументов:

```
def xcv(a = int(input("vvedite pervoe chislo")), b = int(input("vvedite vtoroe chislo"))):
    if a > 5 and b > 5:
        print(a / b)
        xcv()

    else:
        print("Finish")

xcv()
```

Надеюсь, что это Вам помогло.

Comment: огромное спасибо, помогло)))

Comment: @КириллМаликов если мой ответ правильный, пожалуйста, отметьте его правильным, нажав на галочку возле него.